# Trigger Membership Status Calculation for all memberships manually?

Tags: civimember

I've had to amended membership statuses and have a large amount of memberships with the wrong status.

Is there a easy way of triggering these to be recalculated across all memberships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CiviCRM schedule job 'Update Membership Statuses' that calculates membership status and updates the membership. You can either execute it manually through browser or turn on and run through cli or cron.

Comment: Cheers, I found it, didn't setup / configure it :)